# Возврат удобочитаемой версии места

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Не получается вернуть название места, используя для запроса свойство `address` класса `GeocoderRequest`. В чем ошибка?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="geo()">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function geo() {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var geocoderReq = new google.maps.GeocoderRequest();
                geocoderReq.address = "London";
                geocoder.geocode(request: geocoderReq, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            var place = results[0].formatted_address;
                            alert(place);
                            return place;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("no");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                alert(place);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _Не получается вернуть название места_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то непонятное у Вам в строке `geocoder.geocode(request: geocoderReq...`  Формат входных данных, судя по [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest)  в Вашем случаи должен иметь вид к примеру: `{ 'address': address}` - адрес строкой. Также возможно через `location: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}`

В итоге получается нечто такое: *(на выходе - Лондон, Великобритания)*

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var geocoderRequest = {
    address: "London"
}
geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var place = results[0].formatted_address;
        console.log(place); // Лондон, Великобритания
    }
});
```